# Why is JQuery click function not working in succeeding pages of dataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have this code that displays a list of topics with delete and edit buttons in a datatable.

Display.php

```
<table data-toggle="table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" name="all_topic"></th>
                    <th>Topic</th>
                    <th>Date Created</th>
                    <th>Date Update</th>
                    <th>Options</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php 
                     $topics = array();
                     $faq = new Faq; 
                     $topics = $faq->all();
                ?>
                <?php  $i = 1;
                   foreach($topics as $topic) : ?>
                    <tr id="tr-id-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="tr-class-<?php echo $topic->id; ?>" data-topic-id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="topic[]" value="<?php echo $topic->id; ?>" class="faq-checkbox"></td>
                        <td id="td-id-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="td-class-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                            <?php echo $topic->topic; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $topic->date_created; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $topic->date_updated; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-info" href="faqs-edit-topic.php?id=<?php echo $topic->id; ?>">Edit</a>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#faq-delete-modal-<?php echo $topic->id; ?>" >Delete</button>
                            <div id="faq-delete-modal-<?php echo $topic->id; ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Topic</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p>Delete  <b><i><?php echo $topic->topic; ?></i></b> ? </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger faq-delete-topic" data-modal-id="faq-delete-modal-<?php echo $topic->id; ?>" data-topic-id="<?php echo $topic->id; ?>" >Delete </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>                   
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.faqs table').dataTable({
    searching: false,
    "order": [[3, 'desc']],
    "columns": [
        { orderable: false, width: "10%" },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { orderable: false, width: "20%" }]
     });

    $("button.faq-delete-topic").click(function(){
    var $topic_id = $(this).attr("data-topic-id");
    var modal_id = "#" + $(this).attr("data-modal-id");
    $.post('faqs-delete-topic.php',{'topic_id': $topic_id}, function(success){
        console.log(success);
        if(success) {
            // $("table tbody tr[data-topic-id="+ $topic_id +"]").remove();
            $(modal_id).modal('hide');
            $('.faqs table').DataTable().row(".tr-class-"+$topic_id).remove().draw(false);
            display_message('Topic successfully deleted.');
        }
    });
});

});
```

Now when I have a long list of topics, datatable automatically creates a pagination to show the list of topics at a time. Whenever I try to delete a topic using the delete button, it shows the modal and then clicking the delete button on the modal deletes the topic, but only on the first page of the datatable. If I try to go to, say the next page of the datatable, the click function in script.js seems that it doesn't recognize the delete action on the modal. I can only delete on the first page on the datatable, but not on the succeeding pages.

What seems to be the problem with this one? Please help. Thanks guys.

Comment: you must add youre logic for each row every time the new rows are shown (for every page), it is best to use proper events from the datatable api, their examples base is pretty generous, check it, you can bind directly to post row render event in your current code

Comment: thanks.. beautiful documentation they have.

Comment: What @mikus said.  Don't forget to update your `aria-hidden` attribute in visible and non-visible elements whenever updating the display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will only bind those on the 1st page as they are the only ones it can select at the time

Try using

```
$("table").on("click","button.faq-delete-topic",function(){
var $topic_id = $(this).attr("data-topic-id");
var modal_id = "#" + $(this).attr("data-modal-id");
disable_delete1_button();
$.post('faqs-delete-topic.php',{'topic_id': $topic_id}, function(success){
    console.log(success);
    if(success) {
        // $("table tbody tr[data-topic-id="+ $topic_id +"]").remove();
        $(modal_id).modal('hide');
        $('.faqs table').DataTable().row(".tr-class-"+$topic_id).remove().draw(false);
        display_message('Topic successfully deleted.');
        remove_disable_delete1_button();
    }
});
```

You might need to bind the click to an ancestor of `table` e.g. `$("body").on("click","button.faq-delete-topic",...);` depending on how the paging works

Comment: thanks man. you just saved my life. i've been trying to figure it out for about 2hours now. I see that I need to bind it to the entire table. thanks again

Comment: did it actually work? I have doubts..  this will only apply to visible elements anyway, not sure how datatable solves your particular cases, but with any server-side paging it will simply not work.Better to count on the datatables native API

Comment: No worries... The answer from @mikus is more tailored to the DataTable plugin. Mine is a very generic jQuery way of doing it.

Comment: BTW.  $("button.faq-delete-topic") selects all the visible buttons in the document, the $("table").on("click","button.faq-delete-topic", ... only cuts the scope to within the table elements, it will not make more of the buttons selected, and therefore won't fix anything here IMO

Comment: yeah, surprisingly @ASG's answer worked.. :) it's true that it only cuts the scope within the table elements. for now I just need that.. thank you for explaining..  i'm exploring the datatables native api to see what other things i can improve on it. thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

Your current logic only applies the click handler to the visible rows. Whenever you change the page, the UI is refreshed and new rows appear, with no click handler applied.

Use the `createdRow` event of datatable to initialize your buttons, just as it's presented here:
https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html

There are multiple other examples worth checking if you're interested in more advanced models. I would also recommend the paging using REST WebService that returns only the amount of pages needed at the moment, instead of getting all of them at once. It's much faster solution for more data.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out.. i'm also reading the api now and i'll be implementing it with my table. thanks